# Sort array in ascendent order in React

Tags: reactjs, sorting

I want to sort an array of cards by name whenever I click on a control button located in another component. I´m using useContext. The sort method is not working when I use it like this.
console.log("array",players.sort((a,b) => b.realName - a.realName)

```
enter code here
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import api from "./api/players"

const APIcontext = createContext();

export function Provider({children}){

    const [players, setPlayers] = useState([]);
    const [currentPlayer, setCurrentPlayer] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {

    const fetchPlayers = async () => {

      try{
        const response = await api.get('/players');
        setPlayers(response.data)         
        
      }

      catch(err){

        if(err.response){
          console.log(err.response.data)
        }else{
           
          console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`)
        }
          
      }
    }
    
    fetchPlayers()
  },[])

  
 const UpdateDetails = (player) => setCurrentPlayer(player)

 const SortAsc = () => {
   
  console.log("array",players.sort((a,b) => b.realName - a.realName))
 }

    return(
        <APIcontext.Provider value={{players, currentPlayer,UpdateDetails, SortAsc}}>{children}</APIcontext.Provider>
    )
}



export default APIcontext;
```

---

Controls Component. Here is the button that sorts the array.

```
    import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import api from "./api/players"

const APIcontext = createContext();

export function Provider({children}){

    const [players, setPlayers] = useState([]);
    const [currentPlayer, setCurrentPlayer] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {

    const fetchPlayers = async () => {

      try{
        const response = await api.get('/players');
        setPlayers(response.data)         
        
      }

      catch(err){

        if(err.response){
          console.log(err.response.data)
        }else{
           
          console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`)
        }
          
      }
    }
    
    fetchPlayers()
  },[])

  
 const UpdateDetails = (player) => setCurrentPlayer(player)

 const SortAsc = () => {
   
  console.log("array",players.sort((a,b) => b.realName - a.realName))
 }

    return(
        <APIcontext.Provider value={{players, currentPlayer,UpdateDetails, SortAsc}}>{children}</APIcontext.Provider>
    )
}



export default APIcontext;
```

---

card Component. This is the component I want to render the sorted cards

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext } from "react";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import APIcontext from "../context";
import Details from "./Details";

function Cards({}) {
  const { players } = useContext(APIcontext);
  console.log("players", players);

  const { UpdateDetails} = useContext(APIcontext)

  return (
    <>
      {players &&
        players.map((player) => (
          <Card
            key={player.id}
            className="mt-4 mx-2"
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              width: "12rem",
              height: "9rem",
              whiteSpace: "nowrap",
              overflow: "hidden",
              textOverflow: "ellipsis",
            }}
          >
            <Card.Body onClick={()=> UpdateDetails(player)}>
             
              <Card.Title>{player.realName}</Card.Title>
              <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">
                {player.playerName}
              </Card.Subtitle>
              <Card.Text>{player.asset}</Card.Text>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        ))}
    </>
  );
}

export default Cards;
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Is `realName` a name with 2 strings or just 1 string? Like `Sebastian Marquez` or just `Sebastian`? And whether they are uppercased or lowercased

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method would be right if it were to sort integer values. However, for this case, you require some additional code.
You first need to convert the strings to lowercase or uppercase, your choice and the compare them in one of 2 ways:
First -

```
objs.sort((a,b) => 
   {
       const aName = a.realName.toLowerCase(), bName = b.realName.toLowerCase();
       return ((aName > bName) ? 1 : ((bName > aName) ? -1 : 0))
   })
```

Second, much simpler:

```
objs.sort((a,b) => a.realName.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - b.realName.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0));
```

Basically, converts the character at position 0 of `realName` to its corresponding ASCII value then compares which is bigger or smaller

Comment: Thanks, it's working. But how can I actually get the card to display sorted when clicking the button?

Comment: You could update the `players` state inside your `SortAsc` function like this: ```const SortAsc = () => setPlayers(players.sort((a,b) => a.realName.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - b.realName.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0)))``` Hopefully, this works. Upvote the answers as well :P

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time. I tried this but is not working.

Comment: Right, there's this propert in React which prevents DOM updates if we try to mutate `state` values and store them directly. So instead try this ```const SortAsc = () => {
   const sortedPlayers = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(players));
   setPlayers(sortedPlayers.sort((a,b) => a.realName.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - b.realName.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0)))
 }```

Comment: Note: This is not a great solution for deeply nested objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 players.sort((a,b)=>b.realName === a.realName ? 0 : a.realName > b.realName ? 1 : -1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I tried but it is console log in the array exactly how it comes from the database.